# Get contents between two locations in a text file using bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to get the contents between two locations in a text file.
The text file varies in the number of lines between this two location.

example

```
   Location1:  
   more lines..
   mores lines.
   more lines..
   Location2
```

These two locations can appear at the beginning of the text file or in the middle.

I have managed to get to Location1 using

```
cat filename | grep -A 10 Location1
```

However the number of lines between the two locations is not fixed to 10.

Comment: `sed -n '/Location1/,/Location2/p' filename` or `awk '/Location1/,/Location2/' filename`

Comment: if you know with *100% certainty* that a) each 'start' has a matching 'end' and b) the strings that make up the 'start/end' do not show up anywhere else in the file, a couple ideas: `sed -n '/Location1/,/Location2/p'` or `awk '/Location1/,/Location2/'`; keep in mind these are very simplistic answers that break quite easily if you cannot guarantee with *100% certainty* the two prerequisites I've mentioned

Comment: Can there be two-digit numbers in the file after the string `Location` (e.g. `Location10`)?

Comment: Take a look: [How to print lines between two patterns, inclusive or exclusive (in sed, AWK or Perl)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38972736/3776858)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you need one bash command or a script, but you can achieve the goal using following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

FILENAME=$1
LINE_1=$2
LINE_2=$3

idx_1=$(awk "/$LINE_1/{ print NR; exit }" $FILENAME)
idx_2=$(awk "/$LINE_2/{ print NR; exit }" $FILENAME)

# Debug
echo "$LINE_1 idx: $idx_1"
echo "$LINE_2 idx: $idx_2"

cat $FILENAME | awk "{if (NR > $idx_1 && NR < $idx_2) print \$0}"
```

Test file:

```
more lines...
Location1
more lines..
mores lines.
more lines..
Location2
more lines...
more lines..
```

Launch example:

```
./get_content_between_lines.sh sample.txt Location1 Location2
Location1 idx: 2
Location2 idx: 6
more lines..
mores lines.
more lines..
```

Answer (score 0):

pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) solution

```bash
#!/bin/bash

filename=$1;

# find the line numbers of matches
mapfile -t index < <(grep -hn -e Location1 -e Location2  $filename  | grep -o '^[[:digit:]]\+');

# subtract them to get the offset
declare -i grep_offset=$((index[1] - index[0]));

# no need to use ${} inside ((...)) operator 
# declare -i grep_offset=$((${index[1]} - ${index[0]}));

# decrease by one, to ignore second match
let --grep_offset

# match from first one up to $grep_offset , then tail it + ignoring first match
grep -A $grep_offset Location1 $filename | tail -n $grep_offset
```

#### input

```bash
something above
something above
something above
something above
Location1
more lines..
more lines..
mores lines.
mores lines.
more lines..
more lines..
Location2
something below
something below
something below
something below
```

#### output

```bash
more lines..
more lines..
mores lines.
mores lines.
more lines..
more lines..
```

---

Perl one-liner **including the matches**:

```bash
perl -lne '$/=unset; /Location1.*Location2/gs &&  print $&' file.txt 
Location1
more lines..
more lines..
mores lines.
mores lines.
more lines..
more lines..
Location2
```

Perl one-liner **excluding the matches**

```bash
perl -ne '$/=unset; /(?<=Location1\n).*(?=Location2)/gs && print $&' file.txt
more lines..
more lines..
mores lines.
mores lines.
more lines..
more lines..
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '/Location1/{f=1; next} /Location2/{f=0} f{print}' file
more lines..
mores lines.
more lines..
```